# Python If not equal several conditions

Tags: python

My aim is to retrieve API from Coinmarketcap and find the sum of market cap **without** stablecoins.

I use Python and basic loop with if-else.
The problem is that I have to check this condition of let's say 500 coins against the set of stablecoins such as "USDT", "USDC", "BUSD".

Below is my attempt for just one condition, but I also need to sum up market cap if they're not USDC and BUSD and other stablecoins.

```
for item in data["data"]:
    crypto_cap = item["quote"]["USD"]["market_cap"]
    crypto_symbol = item["symbol"]
    if crypto_symbol != "USDT":
        cap_sum += crypto_cap
print(market_cap)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? `if crypto_symbol not in ['list', 'of', 'coins']`…?

Answer (score 3):

You might use `not in` check against list in this case as follows, replace

```
if crypto_symbol != "USDT":
```

using

```
if crypto_symbol not in ["USDT", "USDC", "BUSD"]:
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Much appreciated :)